# Questions that don't make sense without reading chat logs

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Consider this question:

[Why does my app crash when I tap the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443148/why-does-my-app-crash-when-i-tap-the-background)

The question at first glance seems to be a perfectly acceptable question for Stack Overflow.  An experienced Objective-C/iOS developer, however, will take one glance at it and know that there are not quite enough details in the question to give a specific answer to the actual problem.

And the first comment to the question perfectly illustrates the problem:

> The code you have shown is unrelated to the crash you have received. The exception tells you that a `resignFirstResponder` message was sent to an instance of `NSCFString` - my guess is that you have assigned a string to your background image instead of a UIImage from the string or something like that. You should show the code where you set the background

The question can be answered with very general advice, but at this point, the question is now basically just a duplicate of any other `unrecognized selector sent to instance` question in Objective-C (especially when we don't have in the question the exact section of code that is actually *causing* the error and can't give specific advice).

And after a string of comments, the discussion regarding the question eventually moves to a chat room. Two comments after the chat invite, we see this comment:

> @Zhang gave me a solution in the chat. I'm going to let him post that so he can get some points.

So, they rubber-ducked it out in the chatroom, and that's fine. But is the rest fine? **"I'm going to let him post that so he can get some points."**

The question is posted in such a way that no one else can possibly answer it with specific detail. The posted *and accepted* answer points to an *unposted* method in the user's code which needs to be changed.

So either the question is...

- a duplicate of any other `unrecognized selector` questions and the answer is to follow the general sorts of troubleshooting you do when encountering this exception
- unclear what you're asking, because there is NO WAY there's enough detail in the question itself to be able to get to the solution in the accepted answer.

So either the question needs to be closed, or the user needs to add more details into the question (the details that were hashed out in chat/comments) so that the question and answer make more sense to someone else browsing Stack Overflow looking for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: Having a chat background info, doesn't improve the quality of a question. What's written in the post counts, simply like that. So down/close vote it for the usual reasons.

Comment: Perhaps they should improve the question by editing in the relevant parts they discussed in chat. Then I see no problem with the question/answer.

Comment: Exactly -- comment left to that effect.

Comment: This is one of the several reasons why moving extended discussions to chat is wrong.

Comment: @zwol In the end, the details should *still* be in the *question* itself.  Not in chat, and not in comments, but in the actual question.

Comment: @nhgrif I agree in principle but have encountered numerous cases where rewriting the question (or answer) to the point where the attached comments became superfluous was *way* more work than it was worth.

Comment: @zwol In that case, it wasn't chat that was the problem, but the comments.

Comment: @NathanTuggy No. The comments were, in fact, excellent, and the dialogue format precisely suited the material added to the question.  The *only* problem was the system treating them as secondary.

Comment: @zwol: My point is, you take issue either with the general policy of putting everything relevant in the post itself, or else you take issue with comments as much as with chat. Singling out move-to-chat as the greatest problem is not explained by your stated reasoning.

Comment: @NathanTuggy My fundamental objection is to the treatment of comments as second-class and ephemeral rather than first-class and permanent. Thus I object to *both* the policy of folding material back into the question or answer even when that doesn't make sense, *and* the policy of taking "long" discussions away from the question or answer (which I believe *never* makes sense).

Comment: if chat is invoked on a post and then an answer posted by somebody involved in that chat, then would it be plausible to ask when that answer is accepted if the chat helped produce this answer and if so automatically append the chat transcript to the foot of the post?

Comment: Like a way to solve it - SO have to concentrate people attention on "do not forget about edit your post with added important marks from comments " sry for bad eng

Answer (score 11):

We have a perfect close reason for this:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

If the code isn't there and what we have is insufficient to reproduce or understand the problem, it isn't on-topic.  Burn it with fire.

Answer (score 4):

"Unrecognized selector sent to instance" questions should all be closed IMHO. Because these kind of questions bothered me, I once added a paragraph to the iOS tag wiki:

> Please follow the article [My App crashed. Now what?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) by Ray Wenderlich, before posting any questions relating to app crashes. It explains how to properly debug an iOS-App. It's pointless to ask questions relating to crashes when you don't have a *proper* backtrace and exception message.

I don't say that everyone should read this article, but I think that everyone who *demonstrates* by their question that they haven't read it, should have their question closed ;)

At first, this may seem rude, but when you think about it: how can anyone who lacks basic debugging abilities in iOS, work as an iOS developer?

I would vote for "unclear what you are asking", probably accompanied by a link to this meta post. E.g.:

> I have flagged this post as "unclear what you are asking", because it is just another duplicate of the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" problem and it lacks specific information to solve the issue. A discussion on how to solve these kinds of issues can be found in [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1). See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289352/754705) for discussions.